# Retrieving the property information in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, nosql

I had created many classes with properties in orient Db. Now i want to retrieve only the property information.
In MySQL we are using query "desc table Name'

in orient Db which query is used to get the property details with out the data embedded in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select @type, @rid, @version, @class from v
```

where **v** is your class.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in example query for metadata as documented in  http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL.html#query-metadata

You can retrive property name with :

select name from (select expand(properties) from ( select expand(classes) from metadata:schema ) where name = 'OUser')

```
   
+----+--------+
|#   |name    |
+----+--------+
|0   |status  |
|1   |password|
|2   |name    |
|3   |roles   |
+----+--------+
```